# Teradata with SQLAlchemy cannot open shared object file teradatasql.so

Tags: sqlalchemy, teradata, teradatasql

I'm trying to connect to a Teradata database with SQLAlchemy using:

```bash
$ pip list | grep -i teradatasql
teradatasql                 20.0.0.0
teradatasqlalchemy          17.20.0.0
```

The first time I try to connect with the following connection string:

```py
conn_string = f'teradatasql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}'
```

I get this error:

```
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/teradatasql/teradatasql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But any subsequent call would return a different error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'goCombineJSON'"
```

How can I connect to Teradata using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: With your venv activated, see if `pip list | grep -i teradatasql` shows you any results.

Comment: hi @GordThompson, I've updated my question with the pip output, thanks!

Comment: Can you connect using just the teradatasql driver, e.g., `import teradatasql; con = teradatasql.connect(host="whomooz", user="guest", password="please")` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried but with the same error.. My guess right now is that teradatasql package won't work on arm64 architecture, but it would on amd64..

Comment: That could be. I see a note in the ChangeLog about adding ARM support for Mac, but nothing one way or the other regarding Linux.

Comment: I tried changing my Docker image to `python-3.11-buster` (linux/amd64) and it's working, thanks @Fred